# jQuery selectors after dynamic reload, and $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some help. I load a list of entries in a div every 5 seconds. Each entry is a div and has a unique ID. Like this:

```
<div class="entry">
<div class="textbox">
    <p class="entry-text">
        <?php echo $text;?>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="infobox">
    <p class="date"><a #<?php echo $id;?> id="<?php echo $id;?>" href="gen_details.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo $t;?></a> </p>
    <p class="ip"><?php echo $ip;?></p>
</div>
```

These, as I said are loaded each 5 seconds. I'm adding a details page for every entry, with this:

```
                $('.date a').click(function () {
                var dataString = 'id=' + $(this).attr("id"); 
                //alert(dataString);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "gen_details.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#content").hide().fadeOut('fast');
                        $("#content").html(data).show('fast');
                        refresh = 0;
                    },
                });
                return false;
            });
```

This works perfectly fine, until it reloads. It seems to lose the handle for the a href and instead of doing the procedure it goes to gen_details.php

I have tried to use .on() but I don't know how would I get the ID of the entry using .on(), as I cant use $(this) (afaik).

I hope I explained my problem at least half-well. English is not my first language so it wasn't that easy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you keep track of the seconds in your script? Could you please post that part?

Comment: Sure thing. I use window.setInterval(); Like this:     window.setInterval(function(){update(0);}, 5000);

Comment: Ah, good! What do you use refresh for though?

Comment: You are ripping the bound event out every time you purge the html of the `#content` div. The event needs to be rebound each ajax call.

Comment: the update(); function:      function update(flashy) {
      if (flashy == 0) {
       $('#content').load('gen_content.php');//.fadeOut('fast').fadeIn('fast');
      } else {
       $('#content').load('gen_content.php').fadeOut('fast').fadeIn('fast');
       left = 240;
       $('#text_counter').text(left);
       document.getElementById('new-entry').value = document.getElementById('new-entry').defaultValue;
      }
     } I just load a DIV. If you just want to refresh use this: window.setInterval(function(){document.location.reload(true);}, 5000);

Comment: There's something about your code though... Why are you using `.click` on links you're actually intending to use?

Comment: They are not supposed to be used, yet. @Austin how do I do that? Thanks.

Comment: have you used your .on() this way: $('#content').on('click', '.date a', function(){...}); ?

Comment: @NikkoReyes Yep, the problem with that is that $(this) wont work. And I don't know any other way to get the ID of the clicked entry. Thanks.

Comment: @user2031201 if you use .on() that way, $(this) should refer to '.date a', when you tried that, what does $(this) refer to?

Comment: @NikkoReyes Yep, it works now, thanks. I used $(content) instead. Thought it was the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this selector

```
$('div').on('click', '.date a', function () {
```

This will delegate the event to its parent div. So it should work for dynamically created elements as well.

Comment: missing a comma after 'click'

Answer (score 2):

```
Live click event bind event handler to element even after you reload some element. Default click event bind to element when a page load once you reload that element then it also delete event handler of that element.
works on till jquery 1.7 version.

    $('.date a').live('click',(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
                    var dataString = 'id=' + $(this).attr("id"); 
                    //alert(dataString);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "gen_details.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        success: function(data) {
                            $("#content").hide().fadeOut('fast');
                            $("#content").html(data).show('fast');
                            refresh = 0;
                        },
                    });

                });
//when jQuery > 1.7 then used this method

$('body').on('click' '.date a',function () {
  //call 
 });
```

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.9, .live() was removed on this version. Thanks.

Comment: for jquery 1.9 use $(document).on("click",'.date a',function(){});